# Doubt of selecting only affine algebraic sets for defining affine coordinate ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

In Hartshorne section $1.1$ he defines affine coordinate ring to be $A/I(Y)$ where $Y\subset \mathbb {A}^n$ is an affine algebraic set and $A=k[x_1,...,x_n]$.

My question is why it involves only affine algebraic sets instead of taking arbitrary subset as $Y$ as $I(Y)$ is defined for each subset of $\mathbb A^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done. However, there isn't a loss of generality because if you define, for an ideal $I\subseteq k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, the algebraic set $V(I)=\{x\in \Bbb A^n(k)\,:\, \forall p\in I,\ p(x)=0\}$, then $I(Y)=I(V(I(Y)))$ for all $Y\subseteq \Bbb A^n$. It's similar to the reason why you could define the zero set of a family of polynomials, but you do not lose generality by considering only the case when the family is an ideal.

Comment: Is that because $\sqrt {I(Y)}= I(Y)$ (since $f\in \sqrt I(Y) \Rightarrow f^k\in I(Y) $ for some k, hence $f^k(P)=0 $ for all P in Y so, $f(P)=0$ for all P in Y)?

Comment: So, restricting to the set of all affine algebraic sets would actually give me the same family of coordinate rings, with added advantage that it will be in one one correspondence with the set of all algebraic sets. Is that alright?

Comment: I think it will not be one one correspondence because for different algebraic sets we may have isomorphic coordinate rings.

Comment: @NabakumarBhattacharya The correspondence $I:\{\text{algebraic subsets of }\Bbb A^n\}\to \{\text{ideals associated to subsets of }\Bbb A^n\}$ is injective (and surjective by definition) because of $V(I(V(J)))=V(J)$. The correspondence with isomorphism classes of coordinate rings is not injective. The fact that $I(Y)$ is always radical does not really come into play in the proof of $I(V(I(Y)))=I(Y)$: one inclusion is a tautology and the other is just because $A\subseteq B\Rightarrow I(A)\supseteq I(B)$.

Comment: Yeah I realised later that in both the proofs for $IVI(Y) =I(Y) $ and $VIV(J) =V(J) $ nullstellensatz is not being used (means I can prove it without going to nullstellensatz) but the ideals corresponding to algebraic sets are radical or the affine coordinate rings are reduces this is the application of nullstellensatz.

Comment: @NabakumarBhattacharya The fact that $\sqrt{I(Y)}=I(Y)$ (i.e. that the ideal associated to a subset is radical) is elementary and it's always true. Nullstellensatz says that $I(V(J))=\sqrt J$ for all ideals $J$ if and only if the underlying field is algebraically closed. In $\Bbb R[x]$, for instance, $I(\emptyset)=(1)$ is still radical, but what happens is that $I(V(x^2+1))=(1)\supsetneq \sqrt{(x^2+1)}$.

Comment: You are right I was misunderstanding. Thanks.